# In VBA, how to split a string into an array, then pass it as an argument to a Sub or Function

Tags: arrays, function, vba, arguments

**MY QUESTION:**

Is there a way to split a string into an array, then pass that as an argument to a Sub or Function that is expecting an array?

---

**THE DETAILS**:

I have two simple VBA Subs below.  Sub foo() splits a string into an array, then tries to pass it to Sub bar().

```
Sub foo()
    aTest = Split("1,2,3", ",")
    bar (aTest)
End Sub

Sub bar(ByRef aArray())
    ' Do something
End Sub
```

However, they won't compile; in the line `bar (aTest)` the parameter isn't recognized as an array. Here's the error:

```
Compile error:
Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected
```

I think the error is happening because the compiler doesn't interpret the `Split` command as making the variable into an array. (If that's a wrong assumption, let me know!)

Comment: use `Sub bar(ByRef aArray)` instead `Sub bar(ByRef aArray())`

Comment: @simoco Well shoot, that was simple! I'd run into this problem when I was clarifying the variable type in the receiving Sub: `Sub bar(ByRef aArray as String)`. Once I treat the variables and arguments as Variants (ugh), VBA is fine with it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't seem to like using Variants, you are free to be more specific if you want:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim aTest() As String
    aTest = Split("1,2,3", ",")
    Debug.Print TypeName(aTest) 'String()
    bar aTest
End Sub

Sub bar(ByRef aArray() As String)
    ' Do something
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW! I can't believe I didn't try that! I'll have to look back at all my tests see what I did differently in each of them.